# how do I move a node express project to cloud 9 IDE?

Tags: express, cloud9-ide

I have an existing node express project and wanted to easily move it to cloud 9 ide.

Is there a way that I can bulk upload the folders or the entire folder tree rather than dragging individual files to the browser?

Also, I noticed that the create express app command does not work in the console, e.g.

$ express /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FTP to move you stuff over to C9 or move your stuff to Git and then pull it from Git into C9.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also use GitHub or BitBucket to store your project and to access your it by cloning it into Cloud9.

Furthermore, we will soon introduce file-upload, which enables you to drag and drop entire folders/ projects in the editor.

When you want to use the express app command in console please read this article: http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20908531-run-express-in-cloud9-ide